# 413 Request Entity Too Large phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

alguien sabe como se puede solucionar este error al exportar una db de 14 mb son aproximadamente 143891 registros en un archivo .sql, para ello lo estoy haciendo desde phpmyadmin, al momento de exportalo me aparece este error **413 Request Entity Too Large** las configuraciones que tengo en el php.ini son las siguientes

```
upload_max_filesize=200M
max_file_uploads=20
post_max_size=200M
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, pregunta tonta pero por si acaso.. Reiniciaste el servicio luego de modificar el archivo?

Comment: asi es, ya lo reinicie pero aun me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Veo que estas trabajando con nginx no se si estoy mal pero me parece que estás modificando los archivos que usa apache. Revisa éste link al parecer hay que modicar el archivo ngix.conf https://www.keycdn.com/support/413-request-entity-too-large

Comment: Me equivoqué estas modificando el archivo php.ini te faltaría ver el de nginx que comentan alli

Comment: vale muchas gracias por el punto, es de mucha ayuda